# How do I create a menu based on 2 different vocabularies?

Tags: navigation, taxonomy-terms

I'm new to Drupal 7 and I'm trying to create something simple but I can't work out how to do it.

In short, I'd like to create a dropdown list within the main menu that shows all my venues categorised by regions.

To do so, I've created a vocabulary "Regions" that lists my regions. I've created another vocabulary "Venues" with an extra *region* term-field to associate it to a region.
I'd like to have my main menu looking like below:

```
Home
Venues (dropdown)
  > region 1
     - venue 1
     - venue 2
  > region 2
    >> sub-region 2.1
      - venue 3
      - venue 4
    >> sub-region 2.1
      - venue 5
      - venue 6
  > region 3
     - venue 7
     - venue 8
```

I've tried using the taxonomy menu module to achieve that and I can get the first part working, i.e. displaying the regions and sub-regions in the main menu. But then, I have no idea how to populate the regions with their venues based on the extra region field added in that vocabulary.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.